# Passing Different Templates in Django Form Wizard

Tags: django, templates, formwizard

I want to pass different template in each step for my django form wizard.

I want to check each step from form wizard's get_template() function. If I try :

```
def get_template(self,step):
    if step == 1:
        return 'test_1.html'
    return 'test_2.html'
```

It returns test_2.html. I'm checking my steps from my template and generate a form according to step's number but it doesn't seem to good way to do this. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs on [Advanced `FormWizard` methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#advanced-formwizard-methods), `step` is a zero-based counter.

So on the first form, `step` is `0`, not `1`. Could that be catching you out? You might want to change your code to:

`if step == 0:`